# Values are saved from Spark Dataset in parquet file with wrong timezone

Tags: java, spring, apache-spark, timezone, parquet

I use Spark and Java, do some calculations and save them in parquet file in AWS.
The problem happens with all dates, when I debug column (check it dataset with show(), for instance) I get `2024-02-16 00:01:00.000` with time zone `ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin")`.
After checking in file itself it is `2024-02-15 23:01:00.000`.

1. I read the request to take refTime and use it in new dataset

```
routingOptionsRawDs = routingOptionsRawDs.withColumn(REF_TIME, fromLongToTimestamp(routingOptionsRawDs, REF_TIME));
```

```
private static Column fromLongToTimestamp(Dataset<Row> routingOptionsRawDs, String colName) {
        return from_unixtime(routingOptionsRawDs.col(colName).divide(1000), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").cast("timestamp");
    }
```

**All POJO dates mapped then to Dataset are java.time.Instant**

2. All manupulations with data (if ever) happens with `public static final ZoneId ZONE_ID = ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin");`
3. Saving part looks like:

```
dataset.repartition(1)
       .write()
     //.option("timeZone", "Europe/Berlin")
       .mode("overwrite")
       .parquet(tempParquetFilePath.toString());
```

**Dependencies:**

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.13</artifactId>
            <version>${spark-core_2.13.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.13</artifactId>
            <version>${spark-core_2.13.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

I tried different Spark configs
`.config("spark.sql.datetime.java8API.enabled", "true")` have no impact
`.config("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "Europe/Berlin")` have no impact
`.config("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "UTC")` changes the timezone to `2024-02-15 23:01:00.000` when debugging
`.config("spark.sql.parquet.outputTimestampType", "TIMESTAMP_MICROS")` the parquet file table descriptions shows (ni DuckDb) it saved as Timestamp with timezone, but result was the same. When default int96 is used the description shows just Timestamp
`.config("spark.sql.parquet.timestampNTZ.enabled", "false")` great hopes on that, but also no impact true or false

I know in parquet files the field has option `isAdjustedToUTC = true/false` but I cannot find where it could be set up.